# Check against nil for a non optional var

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to save a picture to a photo album, I would like to check asynchronously that everything went good. So I'm using

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(halfFinalPic, self, Selector("image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"), nil);
```

My callback function looks like

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) { }
```

But I don't really understand how to deal with my error object.
I can't check it against nil since it is not a pointeur, so how can I figure out whether or not an error has occurred ?

Comment: Why is `NSError` parameter not optional? If it could be `nil`, it should be optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [UIKit Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) documents only the Objective-C form
of the callback, which is

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

The Swift view of this method is

```
func image(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

where `image` and `error` are implicitly unwrapped optionals.
So `error` can be `nil` and this worked in my test:

```
func image(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println("success")
    }
}
```